# Flash Drives Installer?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, usb-drive

I know I used to be able to install Ubuntu on a flash drive, then install it on a hard drive, using the flash, instead of a CD. Its been a few years since I've had to install from a flash drive, so I'm wondering, is it still possible, and if so, how? Also any information on dual-boot with Windows 7 64bit would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Those are actually two questions. Can you move one of them to a new question, please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you still can.  And it's quite intuitive using Ubuntu's Startup Disk Creator.  Search for it in Dash.  Put your USB stick in, browse to the drive, browse to your iso, and hit Make Startup Disk.  [More detailed instructions here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)